# ionic serve fails after renaming app

Tags: rename, ionic-framework

First, I renamed the repository directory for my app, `mv fooapp barapp`. I did a search and replace for literally every instance of every casing of my app's old name, "FooApp", in the repository where it lives. `grep -R -i FooApp *` returns absolutely nothing. I then deleted `node_modules/` and did `npm install` from scratch.

Somehow, somewhy, when I run `ionic serve`, I get a page that reads

`Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/bistenes/Code/fooapp/www/index.html'`

What weird black magic does Ionic do such that `ionic serve` still has the old path cached? How do I make it cut it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: `killall ionic`

After reinitializing the app along the lines of what adamkwadsworth answered with, I found I was still having the same problem, indicating that the problem was not actually in the files, but either the environment or running processes. It turns out that when you run `ionic serve`, even if the process is already running, it will go through a startup sequence. This led me to incorrectly believe that the process was actually terminating at some point. Rather, I still had the same ionic server running from long before any of the renaming. Running `killall ionic` before my next `ionic serve` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before and I did the following:

1. Setup a new Ionic app - ionic start myApp blank
2. Add required platforms - ionic add platform ios/android
3. Copy and paste the 'www' file into the new project
4. Install required 'ngCordova' plugins
5. Build app - ionic build ios
6. Run or Emulate app - ionic run/emulate ios/android

I hope this helps, 
Good luck.